# Java - Convert RAW to JPG/PNG

Tags: java, image, png, jpeg

I have an image captured by a camera, in RAW `BGRA` format (byte array).
How can I save it to disk, as a `JPG/PNG` file?

I've tried with `ImageIO.write` from Java API, but I got error IllegalArgumentException (image = null)

CODE:

```
try
{
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
    BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(input);

    String path = "D:/image.jpg";

    ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File(path));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}
```

Note that "img" is the RAW byte array, and that is NOT null.

Comment: If `ImageIO.write(...)` complains that `image == null`, that means that you have no image. Can you show the code you use to read in the raw image, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `ImageIO.read` does *not* support raw RGB (or BGRA in your case) pixels. It expects a *file format*, like BMP, PNG or JPEG, etc.

In your code above, this causes `bImageFromConvert` to become `null`, and this is the reason for the error you see.

If you have a `byte` array in BGRA format, try this:

```
// You need to know width/height of the image
int width = ...;
int height = ...;

int samplesPerPixel = 4;
int[] bandOffsets = {2, 1, 0, 3}; // BGRA order

byte[] bgraPixelData = new byte[width * height * samplesPerPixel];

DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(bgraPixelData, bgraPixelData.length);
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, samplesPerPixel * width, samplesPerPixel, bandOffsets, null);

ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

System.out.println("image: " + image); // Should print: image: BufferedImage@<hash>: type = 0 ...

ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(path));
```

Note that JPEG is not a good format for storing images with alpha channel. While it is possible, most software will not display it properly. So I suggest using PNG instead.

Alternatively, you could remove the alpha channel, and use JPEG.

Comment: Yes, remove the alpha! What kind of camera can take a photo with alpha information? (The choice between JPEG and PNG depends on whether a certain loss of data is preferable over the final file size.)

Comment: @Jongware Good point. I was wondering about that too. Maybe the camera just uses 32 bit alignment for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code, but it stores to disk a transparent image if I choose PNG format or a dark image if I choose JPG format.
How can I solve this?

Comment: @ssnake As Jongware says, remove the alpha. Your image doesn't really have alpha, rather it is RGB + 0-pad.

Comment: had to change samplesPerPixel = 4; to samplesPerPixel = 3;
int[] bandOffsets = {2, 1, 0, 3}; // BGRA order to int[] bandOffsets = {2, 1, 0}; // BGR order , first false argument to true in the constructor  ComponentColorModel(...) and it worked!!

Answer (score -1):

With Matlab you can convert all types of images with 2 lines of code:

```
img=imread('example.CR2');
imwrite(img,'example.JPG');
```

Comment: This question is around Java, Matlab is non mentioned.